# Issue with legend coloring in an RDLC

Tags: asp.net, reporting, rdlc

I'm working on a report using a business object data set. The business object is really simple it has three fields (ColorName, ColorCode, Date). I'm making a bar chart using the year from the Date as the category, ColorName as the series field, and count of ColorName as the "data" (the top area in the designer) field. So the graph will show each year along the bottom with series bars of the colors. In the "Series Properties" I have the fill set to ColorCode and my color code values are HTML color codes including the pound sign. The bar graph is working perfectly. The bars are the correct colors. The legend however is inconsistent. My current graph has 5 colors and only 3 of them are showing the correct color in the legend swatch. Two of them are black but they shouldn't be. If I change the color code for a ColorName then the graph updates correctly but the swatch is still black. I have another graph that is a pie chart which is doing the same thing but the legend works correctly in that one. Anybody have an idea where I can look to resolve this legend color issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like if any year had no series values then the legend would not work correctly. And it seems to only happen when you add a series to the report. The solution was to update my query to return counts instead of rows; including 0 counts for series that had no records. This way every series/category group had it's own record in the data set.

Answer (score 0):

I have applied the same case for Rating Score 1 to 5. For each series I needed to color each bar in the Bar Chart according to the following factors (1:Poor, 2:Average, 3:Good, 4:Very Good, 5:Excellent).

- Right click on any bar in the chart and select Series Properties.
- Select Fill, Set background fill options - Fill Style to Solid.
- Enter the below formula in the formula editor:

  **=IIF(Fields!Rating.Value=1, "Tomato", IIF(Fields!Rating.Value=2, "Orange", IIF(Fields!Rating.Value=3, "#cdf8cd", IIF(Fields!Rating.Value=4, "#7de67d", "Lime"))))**

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I actually figured it out and forgot to post the answer. I'll post it now.